# didn't get a specific answer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm working with ruby and consuming an api called **food2fork.com**
where i have two files 
`recipes_controller.rb` and `recipes.rb`

```
#recipes.rb

require 'httparty'

class Recipe
  include HTTParty 

  default_options.update(verify: false)
  base_uri "http://food2fork.com/api"
  default_params  key: ENV["FOOD2FORK_KEY"]
  format :json

  def self.for (para)
    get("/search",query: {q:para})["recipes"]
  end
end
```

and the second file `recipes_controller.rb`

```
require_relative 'recipes'
puts Recipe.for("chocolate")
```

but when i run `recipes_controller.rb` file in command line.i get an error

```
    `
  C:\Users\Hamza\module-3-assignment-1>ruby recipes_controller.rb
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse': 
  822: unexpected token at 'FORBIDDEN' (JSON::ParserError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/json/common.rb:156:in ` 
   parse'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httparty- 
    0.16.2/lib/httparty/parser.rb:125:in `json'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httparty- 
    0.16.2/lib/httparty/parser.rb:145:in `parse_supported_format'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httparty- 
   0.16.2/lib/httparty/parser.rb:110:in `parse'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httparty- 
   0.16.2/lib/httparty/parser.rb:69:in `call'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httparty- 
   0.16.2/lib/httparty/request.rb:391:in `parse_response'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httparty- 
    0.16.2/lib/httparty/request.rb:359:in `block in handle_response'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httparty- 
    0.16.2/lib/httparty/response.rb:25:in `parsed_response'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httparty- 
   0.16.2/lib/httparty/response.rb:96:in `method_missing'
    from C:/Users/Hamza/module-3-assignment-1/receipes.rb:12:in `for'
    from recipes_controller.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Seems like the response isn't JSON. Check if you can visit the URL with your provided key manually. Also is the space at the end of `ENV["a4211b7526158c71df283b3b5097eb36 "]` intentional? Otherwise this might result in a `nil` value passed to the request as key.

Comment: when i tried to access it manually it returns 403 forbidden

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are sending wrong api key

Try to do it like this:

```
class Recipe
    include HTTParty

    key_value = ENV['FOOD2FORK_KEY'] || 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE'

    base_uri "http://food2fork.com/api"
    default_params key: key_value
    default_options.update(verify: false)
    format :json

    def self.for(search_string)
        get('/search', { query: { q: search_string}})["recipes"]
    end
end
```

Comment: yes it works this way.can you tell me what was wrong because before this i was also using right api key provided to me .when i signed up??

Comment: My script setup default key if ENV key is empty

If string `ENV['FOOD2FORK_KEY'] || 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE'` works but string `ENV['FOOD2FORK_KEY']` doesn't works it means that you don't have `FOOD2FORK_KEY` in your ENV, because you have to setup it in your environment before you start your script. Simple example [here](https://rubyplus.com/articles/2261-Ruby-Basics-Setting-Environment-variables)